# Multiple Timers WPF application, The calling thread must be STA Error

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

My WPF application involves several timers. Everything works with DispatcherTimers but the delays are huge and freezes occur often (for example 3 sec freeze then the remaining 3 sec get added at once).

My problem is i am not sure how exactly i have to redesign my application to get around this problem. Never worked with threads before and its my first real WPF application as well.

I get the following error:
**The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this.**

I got this error by replacing my Dispatcher timer by a Timer from the namespace System.Timers

Old code with dispatcher timer:

```
timerW = new DispatcherTimer();
        timerW.Tick += new EventHandler(timerW_Tick);
        timerW.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5000);
        timerW.Start();
```

New code with Timer:

```
            timerW = new Timer();
            timerW.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timerW_Tick);
            timerW.Interval = 5000; 
            timerW.Start();
```

A query gets executed every 5 seconds to retreieve a date value. When certain conditions are met buttons get dynamically created. For example *if the date remains the same for 3 min a button gets created.*

**Dynamic created button contains:**

- Date from the database
- A timer that starts running when the buttons gets created. This timer only stops when a new button gets created, this records the downtime.
- A reason for the downtime

The buttons get saved in a *ObservableCollection* and use Dependency Properties so they get notified when something changes. It is a custom button with several textblocks to display the information.

The button part is where all the interaction is at in my program, the rest of the interface just displays information fro the database. The buttons get placed in a custom made slider like control with left and right navigation buttons.

**So in short my program has 3 different dispatcher timers.**

- One to display the current time (hh:mm:ss format)
- One to execute a sql query and retrieve a date value every 5 sec
- One to update the downtime timer every second inside a dynamically custom styled WPF button. I use a stopwatch to record the downtime in between.

So it seems i need to work with **treads** and/or **backgroundworker**?

Not sure how i actually begin with this since i am pretty clue less for some time now. Some example code would be most welcome.

**Tldr:**

I  use timers for the following reasons:

- Display the current time
- Record downtime (real time, so i actually see it counting by the second)
- A SQL query that gets executed every 5 seconds.

EDIT:

```
public void InitializeDispatcherTimerW()
    {
        TimerCallback callback = MyTimerCallBack;
        timerWegingen = new Timer(callback, null, 0, 5000);

        timerWegingen.Change(0, 5000);
    }

    private void MyTimerCallBack(object state)
    {
        DisplayWegingInfo();
        CaculateTimeBetweenWegingen();
    }
```

Best regards,
Jackz.

Answer (score 1):

[System.Timers.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) seems to require an STA thread. An STA thread was a requirement for Windows Forms, but WPF apparently doesn't need it.

Does [System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) meet your need?

Here is an example:

```
// firstTickInterval and interval are TimeSpans
TimerCallback callback = MyTimerCallback;
Timer timer = new Timer(callback, null, firstTickInterval, interval);
// timer is now running
// To stop the timer, do timer.Change(-1, -1);
```

The callback function would look like this:

```
void MyTimerCallback(object state)
{
    // This is not guaranteed to execute on the UI thread.
    // In this example, state will be null, since we passed null in the Timer constructor.
}
```

Comment: I seem to to be getting a error when i try to declare the tick method when using the Threading timer.

Comment: There is no Tick event/method. What do you mean?

Comment: I mean to execute a certain method every x seconds. How do i do this with this sort of timer?

Comment: You need to pass a TimerCallback, which is a method that returns void and accepts a single object parameter.

Comment: Could you please illustrate what you mean in how i can use this Timer with my old dispatcher code? Not exactly sure what to do in the void method. Thanks.

Comment: I tried executing 2 methods every 5 sec with this timer but my program just shuts down without any warning or error? I have pasted the code in  first post at the bottom. For some reason this kind of syntax is really confusing me compared to the other 2 timer work around.

Comment: Did you test the timer in a console application? If so, then it will shut down immediately. The timer won't hold it open.

Comment: No i just implemented it in my current WPF application to execute certain methods every 5 seconds.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is not using Invoke in the callback. I don't know how much I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

When timers callback code interact with UI elements You need to use:

```
UIElement.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(...);
```

More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx

Comment: The link no longer works -1.  Please put a solution in the answer.