# System.Threading Timer

Tags: c#, wpf, timer

I am having problems converting my DispatcherTimer syntax to the Thread Timer. When i run my application suddenly it shuts down without any error.

Basically i want the timer to execute 2 methods every 5 seconds.

**EDIT: The 2 methods are updating the UI.**
I am trying to attempt to get rid of the DispatcherTimer because i have to much freezes and delays in the UI display.

Dispatcher timer code:

```
timerW = new DispatcherTimer();
    timerW.Tick += new EventHandler(timerW_Tick);
    timerW.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5000);
    timerW.Start();



 private void timerW_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DisplayWegingInfo();
            CaculateTimen();
        }
```

Code for the System.Threading Timer:

```
public void InitializeDispatcherTimerW()
    {
        TimerCallback callback = MyTimerCallBack;
        timerW = new Timer(callback);

        timerW.Change(0, 5000);
    }

    private void MyTimerCallBack(object state)
    {
        DisplayWegingInfo();
        CaculateTime();
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Try commenting out the two functions that you are are executing, and replacing them temporarily with something innocuous, like a Debug.Print. I can't imagine a crash in the code you've already shown, although I'm a bit puzzled that you've apparently initialized the timer twice.

Comment: I am trying to get rid of the dispatcher timer since its produces a a lot of lag in my application. When i comment the MyTimerCallBack the application no longer shut down. Those 2 methods attempt to update the UI.

Comment: A [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) might be more suitable for this. In any case, any updates to the UI from your timer thread can only be safely done with `Control.Invoke`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175186/multiple-timers-wpf-application-the-calling-thread-must-be-sta-error gives a bigger scope of the problem i am trying to solve.  So it would be best just do work with the backgroundworker and ignore the DispatcherTimer / Timer all together? Thanks.

Comment: Well, the `BackgroundWorker` does have the advantage of not requiring you to `Control.Invoke` your UI updates, as the `ReportProgress` delegate is "thread-safe" for UI calls.  You would still need a timer somewhere if you want 5 second update intervals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by the name DisplayWedgingInfo, I would guess this method updates the UI? System.Threading.Timer executes on a thread that is different than the UI thread, so to be able to update the UI from that thread you would need to marshal those calls back to the `Dispatcher` thread using [`Dispatcher::[Begin]Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke.aspx).

So you can leave whatever expensive work that doesn't touch UI elements as is, but for the UI manipulation you would simply do:

```
string someValue = this.SomeExpensiveOperation();

this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
    DispatcherPriority.Background,
    new Action(() => 
   { 
          this.myControl.Text = someValue; 
   }));
```

I should point out that there will be some interruption to any UI interaction/rendering that might be going on when the invocation does occur. This is unavoidable as the execution will happen on the main thread. By using `DispatcherPriority.Background` you at least schedule the update with a priority that keeps it lower than any input that the user might be providing at the time. However, don't expect to be able to make a massive update to the UI without any penalty. If you need to do this it's best to queue up multiple invocations with `Background` priority so that they can happen with higher priority stuff like input in between if necessary.

Comment: Yes it updates the UI. Could you give a small example? Cheers

Answer (score 3):

The problem most likely is that you are updating your UI in the methods in your timer callback. This is only possible from the UI thread and the timer runs in a background thread.

I suggest you stick with the `DispatcherTimer`.

An alternate solution would be to split the code up a bit: Extract the work intensive code into other methods and run them in a background thread and update the UI afterwards from the UI thread.

Something like this:

```
private void MyTimerCallBack(object state)
{
    LongCalculationsThatDontNeedTheUI();
    _dispatcherUIThread.Invoke(new Action(UpdateUI));
}
```

Comment: When i use dispatchertimer i have a lot of freezes and delays. Hence my attempt to change that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175186/multiple-timers-wpf-application-the-calling-thread-must-be-sta-error

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to separate your **data retrieval/calculation** from your **data display**.

As Daniel points out, any GUI updating needs to be done on the Dispatcher thread, so the easiest way is to use `DispatcherTimer`.

However, using `DispatcherTimer` means that **everything** in your timer callback gets done in the GUI thread. This is not good if you have any operations that take an appreciable amount of time. The GUI will stutter and lock up as you have found.

You need to work out what is taking the time. From your other question I would guess that it is the SQL retrieval. In this case you would be better doing the actual **retrieval** on a separate thread (by using `System.Threading.Timer`) and once you have the result, update the **display** by using `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()` to marshal to the GUI thread.

Answer (score 0):

I would check for 2 things:
1.  As some others have said, make sure that if you are updating the UI, that you are Invoking back to the dispatcher -- you can only update the UI from the UI thread.  Even if you are using databinding -- if a timer thread updates a value that is databound to the UI, that "counts" as the wrong thread touching the UI.

1. Always protect your timeer callback with a try..catch block.  .Net's default behavior for unhandled exceptions is to terminate the process.  I've seen lots of "just quit", where the real culprit was no exception handling on a timer thread, or a worker thread.  (in fact, WPF should be throwing an exception if you try to manipulate the UI from the wrong thread, so it could be that you are getting the exception, and then the program terminates because there is no handler)

Answer (score -3):

Why not simply use a background thread to dispatch events?

```
  CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
  Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
     {
          while(!cts.IsCancellationRequested)
          {
               Thread.Sleep(5000);

               this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                  {
                       DisplayWegingInfo();
                       CalculateTimen();
                  }), null);
          }
     });
```

Comment: -1: This has the same problems as the current approach: It tries to updated the UI in a background thread and thus fails.

Comment: The OP didnt mention it updating the UI in those functions. However, I will modify it to correctly be UI thread safe.

Comment: That's now effectively the solution he already had with the `DispatcherTimer`.

Comment: -1: A thread is an expensive resource. Creating one just to have it Sleep 99% of the time is simply wasteful. Plus, waiting in a thread pool thread should generally be avoided - use the thread pool for short tasks, not for long-running operations.